# Call item from array and run foreach

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a powerhell script which will work through an array and perform an action on each item. But I keep getting an empty value

```
if ($number -eq "3") {

write-host "vm01 is $(virtualM1)"

$array = $vm01

}
elseif ($number -eq "2") {

write-host "vm01 is $(virtualM1)"
write-host "vm02 is $(virtualM2)"

$array = $vm01,$vm02

}
elseif ($number -eq "3") {

write-host "vm01 is $(virtualM1)"
write-host "vm02 is $(virtualM2)"
write-host "vm03 is $(virtualM3)"

$array = $vm01,$vm02,$vm03

}
elseif ($number -eq "4") {

write-host "vm01 is $(virtualM1)"
write-host "vm02 is $(virtualM2)"
write-host "vm03 is $(virtualM3)"
write-host "vm04 is $(virtualM4)"

$array = $vm01,$vm02,$vm03,$vm04
    }
$array | ForEach-Object {$_}
```

I was thinking you could use $_ and that referenced each object. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? For something so simple caused tremendous headache :)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Something appears to be missing from your code. Where is `$vm01` (and `$vm02`, etc...) getting assigned a value in the first place?

Comment: If you truly always want to be working with an array,  the scalar scenario needs to be converted to an array -> `$array = ,$vm01`

Comment: Thanks all, you were right the code needed to be changed to `$virtualM1 = "vm2021"
$virtualM2 = "vm2022"
$virtualM3 = "vm2023"

$array = $vm01,$vm02,$vm03

$number = "5"

if ($number -eq "1") {

write-host "vm01 is $virtualM1"

$array = $virtualM1

}
elseif ($number -eq "2") {

write-host "vm01 is $virtualM1"
write-host "vm02 is $virtualM2"


$array = $virtualM1,$virtualM2

}
elseif ($number -eq "3") {

write-host "vm01 is $virtualM1"
write-host "vm02 is $virtualM2"
write-host "vm03 is $virtualM3"


$array = $virtualM1,$virtualM2,$virtualM3

}` Thanks

Comment: @NorrinRad So you managed to solve your problem? If not, please [update your existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68409817/edit) with the actual code you're asking about

Comment: Why use all these `if .. elseif` 's anyway? Using `switch($number){...}` would make your code much more readable.

Comment: @Theo I'm not sure how to do that, do you have a link I could follow ?

Comment: Much simpler solution would be: `$array = $virtualM1,$virtualM2,$virtualM3 |Select -First $number` :-)

Comment: google *switch statement powershell* ;)